# Use javascript to detect if android screen reader is on

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, screen-readers

I have a web page running inside an Android webview. A certain feature should be turned off if screen reader is on, hence I'm looking for a way to use javascript to check Android's screen reader status? I can already do that in APK and communicate with the web page through javascript. That however would require APK update and I try to avoid doing so. A pure javascript solution would be the best but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to make sure someone isn't running another app on top of yours copying the screen

Comment: what are you talking about?